# Kotlin variable usage "variable must be initialize"

Tags: variables, kotlin, initialization

can someone explain can solve this problem in kotlin? Thank you very much

```
var weight = rweight.text.toString().toFloat()
var hct = rhct.text.toString().toFloat()
var EBV :Float
var ABL :Float

if (rman.isChecked){
    EBV = weight * 75
} else if (rwoman.isChecked) {
    EBV = weight * 65
}
ABL = EBV * (10)/hct  //error in here "EBV must be initialize"
```

Comment: try initializing it to something like `var EBV: Float = 0.0`? I think both your if and else if are not true so EBV is null in that line.

Comment: @PhaniRithvij yes, thank you very much for the answer. The problem is in my code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You receive that error because `EBV` may not be initialized when it is used.

You should initialize `EBV` variable with default value:

```
var EBV: Float = 0.0f // or some other default value
```

Or add `else` clause to the condition:

```
EBV = if (rman.isChecked) {
    weight * 75
} else if (rwoman.isChecked) {
    weight * 65
} else {
    0.0f // assign some value to the variable
}

// As improvement you can replace `if` with `when` statement:

EBV = when {
    rman.isChecked -> weight * 75
    rwoman.isChecked -> weight * 65
    else -> 0.0f // assign some value to the variable
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. The second method that uses "when" is work for me.